# "Fragment android:fragment Unable to instantiate fragment" on Tablets

Tags: android

I'm getting the following errors when my app runs on tablets although it seems to run fine in the emulator on a nexus 7:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.myapp/com.my.myapp.PrefsActivity}: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.my.myapp.PrefsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2063)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1168)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4561)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.my.myapp.PrefsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:581)
at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeaderInner(PreferenceActivity.java:1117)
at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeader(PreferenceActivity.java:1150)
at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:551)
at com.my.myapp.PrefsActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:40)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4637)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2027)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.myapp.PrefsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:571)
... 18 more
```

I'm using the Unified Preference library, I put GeneralPreferenceFragment in its out class (instead of an inner class) but this hasn't solved the problem

```
    package com.my.myapp;

import net.saik0.android.unifiedpreference.UnifiedPreferenceFragment;

public class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends UnifiedPreferenceFragment {
   public GeneralPreferenceFragment(){

   }
}
```

GeneralPreferenceFragment is only mentioned in XML in the prefs_headers.xml:

```
    <preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:unified="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<!--
/*
** Header definitions are identical to android:* except for preferenceRes which should be a reference to a preference xml file
** Unlike the native headers these are also used for building the single pane version.
*/
-->
<header
    unified:fragment="com.my.myapp.PrefsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment"
    unified:title="@string/pref_header_general"
    unified:preferenceRes="@xml/pref_general" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.my.myapp.PrefsActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        >
    </activity>
```

Comment: check AndroidManifest.xml for missing declarations

Comment: Have added part of my manifest, looks like the declaration is fine

Comment: I have the exactly same problem. Did you find the answer?

Comment: afraid not, might be a bug in unified preference lib. If you figure it out let me know by answering this question!

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with same problem all morning... finally found a solution. Note, I took screenshots to go with this explanation but I don't have enough rep to post them! Apologies.

I was having these same errors just in getting the UnifiedPreference demo project to build & run, so I assume these steps will help you with your own project too.

First of all, make sure you add actionbarsherlock & UnifiedPreference as library references - jar files won't work as they have layout/xml files!

The demo project actually came with a reference to the UnifiedPreference project named as 'library', but I had renamed it to UnifiedReference, so the demo project could no longer find it. So I had to remove the library reference under Project Properties -> Android -> Library and re-add using the new name. I also added the reference to actionbarsherlock in the same way.

I then added both of these projects to the build path for the demo project in Project Properties - Build Path - Projects, and ticked them in Project Properties - Build Path - Order & Export.

Now, that solves the reference issues.

But now you've probably got some code issues in Eclipse, namely in net.saik0.android.unifiedpreference.UnifiedPreferenceHelper.

Firstly, I had to mark the method loadHeadersFromResource with @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) so eclipse would shut up:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void loadHeadersFromResource(int resid, List<Header> target) {
```

But Eclipse still complained about title & icon headers... namely:

```
sa.peekValue(R.styleable.PreferenceHeader_title); (in 2 places)
...and...
header.iconRes = sa.getResourceId(R.styleable.PreferenceHeader_icon, 0);
```

So, in UnifiedPreference project's res -> values -> atrs.xml, I noticed the title & icon elements had no format attribute. I added in format="string" like so:

```
<attr name="title" format="string" />
...
<attr name="icon" format="string" />
```

But now Eclipse complained that these attributes were already declared. Turns out, they are - in ActionBarSherlock project! So I gave them a new name:

```
<attr name="up_title" format="string" />
...
<attr name="up_icon" format="string" />
```

And changed the code in UnifiedPreferenceHelper accordingly:

```
sa.peekValue(R.styleable.PreferenceHeader_up_title); (in 2 places)
...and...
header.iconRes = sa.getResourceId(R.styleable.PreferenceHeader_up_icon, 0);
```

Refresh & clean dependency projects, then you main project, and voila! No errors in Eclipse, run the Demo project & no ClassNotFoundException errors, and I've now got the demo running on my phone.

Hope this helps someone.

Conor

Comment: Great write up, however it looks like this solution is for a project/eclipse configuration issue you were having? The ClassNotFoundException errors I get are runtime errors from a small percentage of users and I've never experienced them myself

Comment: Aha, reading my answer again I can see how it looks that way. But I was in fact getting the same ClassNotFoundException runtime errors before performing the steps above. Reason why, is that although the demo project was referencing UnifiedPreferences as a library, that path was incorrect because I'd renamed the UnifiedPreferences library, but this didn't cause configuration errors because it still somehow had the JAR file reference. So you could build and run, but it couldn't find resource files or inner classes, hence the ClassNotFoundExceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.myapp.PrefsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment
```

At the first - try to clean project and then try if problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks piotrpo, but I'm able to build the project fine, it's a runtime exception I'm getting.